# Boolean value of a list

Tags: python, list, boolean, counting

I made a function and my result is a list:

```
[3, 3, 3]
```

Now I need to return a boolean value. If all of the elements are 2 or higher, I need to return True otherwise I need to return false. In this case it would be : True. ( Because all the elements are 3 and 3 > 2)
Is there any code to do this quickly?

I tried to make a FOR - loop like:

```
for i in [3, 3, 3]: if i >= 2: return True else: return False
```

I think this is correct but I want to know if there is a faster method.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your efforts.

Comment: okej I'm new here. This is my first question ever here. Next time I will show my efforts. Thx for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) ([generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) here) that yields booleans and pass it to [`all` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
>>> all(x >= 2 for x in [3, 3, 3])
True
```

I see you posted your code, it's not correct as it will only check the first element of the list. You can fix it:

```
for i in your_list: 
    if i < 2: 
        return False # Return early
return True # if `i < 2` was False for all elements in the list, return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a= [3, 3, 3]
b=[elem for elem in a if elem > 2]  
print (a==b)
```

Output: True

or in a more condensed way

```
a= [3, 3, 3]
print([elem for elem in a if elem > 2]==a)
```

Output: True

Comment: The question was about a faster method, not slower and more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def areGreaterEqualThen2(lst):
    if lst:
        return lst[0] >= 2 and areGreaterEqualThen2(lst[1:])
    return True
```

If you have to define your own function.

It also is a fast solution because if the first condition is false, the entire `and` returns false.

Comment: Never thought, that someone would solve this problem recursively in Python.

Comment: @Daniel I've done a lot of Haskell lately so this mindset stuck to me.